# Laravel doesn't shows up with the normal Debug screen

Tags: php, debugging, laravel, frameworks, laravel-5

Today I started using Laravel 5 and the first thing i noticed, was that the debug screen is not like in Laravel 4.2.

Looks like this: http://s30.postimg.org/r0xzjhus1/Screen_Shot_2015_03_30_at_1_15_02_am.png

I thought it would look similar to the Laravel 4.2 with some other colors.
Do I have to activate the 'advanced' view by myself?

Answer (score 0):

To bring back the `error page` of previous version of Laravel, you must install the [whoops package](http://github.com/filp/whoops).

First, `composer require filp/whoops:~1.0`.

Then open `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`, and in the `render()` method, add a Whoops handler. Maybe something like this:

```
/**
 * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Exception  $e
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if ($this->isHttpException($e))
    {
        return $this->renderHttpException($e);
    }


    if (config('app.debug'))
    {
        return $this->renderExceptionWithWhoops($e);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}

/**
 * Render an exception using Whoops.
 * 
 * @param  \Exception $e
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
protected function renderExceptionWithWhoops(Exception $e)
{
    $whoops = new \Whoops\Run;
    $whoops->pushHandler(new \Whoops\Handler\PrettyPageHandler());

    return new \Illuminate\Http\Response(
        $whoops->handleException($e),
        $e->getStatusCode(),
        $e->getHeaders()
    );
}
```

> Ref: [Bringing Whoops Back to Laravel 5 | By Matt Stauffer](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/bringing-whoops-back-to-laravel-5)